# Cannot use method 'updateProp' in RNeo4j package

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I'm using RNeo4j package together with igraph to calculate betweenness centrality and write back to Neo4j database.

It can calculate perfectly without any problem connecting with Neo4j. After I'd got vector named with id of its node and contained its betweenness centrality value, I tried to update only one node and I got problem with 'updateProp' method.

The error I got is this.

```
Error in UseMethod("updateProp") : 
no applicable method for 'updateProp' applied to an object of class "list"
```

And this is some part of my code that stuck.

```
...
bet <- betweenness(g)
alice = getLabeledNodes(neo4j, "User", id = as.integer(names(bet[1])))
# returned valid node
# following line got the mentioned error.
alice = updateProp(alice,betweenness_centrality = as.numeric(bet[[1]]))
```

I also tried other way like this without any luck.
(Also hardcoded the value to be 0 but it didn't work either)

```
newProp = list(betweenness_centrality = bet[[1]])
alice = updateProp(alice,newProp)
```

p.s. for my reference website http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/RNeo4j/man/updateProp.html .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateProp` expects the first argument to be a node. You're passing it a list. It should work if you access the first node of that list.

```
bet <- betweenness(g)
alice = getLabeledNodes(neo4j, "User", id = as.integer(names(bet[1])))
alice = alice[[1]]
# returned valid node
# following line got the mentioned error.
alice = updateProp(alice, betweenness_centrality = as.numeric(bet[[1]]))
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your wonderful package.
I misunderstood the return value of `getLabeledNodes` that it was a node.

I owe you a lot! Cheer!